# What happens to installed packages on a sysupgrade in OpenWRT?

Tags: upgrade, openwrt

I've just upgraded my OpenWRT router from 10.03.1-rc4 to rc5 (testing).

It looks like all my installed packages are gone. Is that the expected behaviour? If yes, I should be able to just reinstalled them and load the configs from the backup, correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The OpenWRT Wiki](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/installation/generic.sysupgrade) says you can't keep existing binaries, but need to reinstall them.

> In particular, any manually installed software packages you may have
>   installed after the initial OpenWrt installation have to be
>   reinstalled after an OpenWrt upgrade. That way everything will match,
>   e.g. the updated Linux kernel and any installed kernel modules.
>
> Any configuration files or data files placed in locations not
>   specifically listed as being preserved below will also be lost in an
>   OpenWrt upgrade. Be sure to check any files you have added or
>   customized from a default OpenWrt install to back up these items
>   before an upgrade.

However, [Tolaris](http://www.tolaris.com/2010/09/02/upgrading-to-openwrt-10-03-1-rc3/) gives the following command to take a list of your installed packages:

```
opkg list-installed | cut -f 1 -d ' '
```

Answer (score 10):

You can backup your list of installed packages:

```
opkg list-installed | cut -f 1 -d ' ' > /etc/config/packages.list
```

(Put it into /etc/config folder so it will get retained between firmware updates)

and then after the update:

```
cat /etc/config/packages.list | opkg install
```

Comment: The `cat` part of this command never works for me so instead I do opkg install $(cat /etc/config/packages.list) which works perfectly :)

Comment: The second command should probably be `cat /etc/config/packages.list | xargs opkg install`.